# QL Translation Question

Tags: logic

I was attempting to translate the statement "All love all.", and then check if it is a logical truth.

I first want to know if my translation is correct. Let $Lxy$ mean x loves y,then

$\forall x \forall yLxy$

Also, after some examination, I believe that this is not a logical truth.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All love all" is hardly Engish. "Everyone loves everyone" would pass muster though. And yes, if the domain of quantification is people and $Lxy$ renders $x$ *loves* $y$, then to be sure "Everyone loves everyone" can be rendered by $\forall x\forall yLxy$.

And how could that possibly be a logical truth??? -- given that, on the intended interpretation, it is plain false, you know it isn't certainly true on *all* possible interpretations!

Comment: Haha you're so great Dr. Smith! I just realized I think I have your logic book! You're text book is a supplement to our main text, but I use yours way more often. Wow that's crazy. But thanks for the laugh and help!